# color ramp red to tan in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I can't get the mesh lips to smoothly color ramp from red to tan. I've tried but the lips keep one color.

Material setup is a mix shader (diffuse & glossy).
I'm trying to make the inside of my model's mouth red, and the face tan. The problem lies in between the mouth and the lips - there is a hard color change which looks bad, and so I must ramp the color red to tan linearly.

Comment: Could you add more information about your material setup, your scene setup and also describe how you intend to use the color ramp for your task?

Comment: Material setup is a mix shader (diffuse & glossy). I'm trying to make the inside of my model's mouth red, face tan, but the problem lies in between the mouth and the lips - there is a hard color change which looks bad, and so I must ramp the color red to tan linearly.

Comment: I could give you a more precise answer if you posted photos of your setup, but what i normally do in this situations is UV unwrap the edges of the lips, straightem them out in the uv editor and use that uv map for the gradient texture that goes into the color ramp.

Comment: [Quickest way to create a color gradient](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/38930/2217)